# Npgsql: connect to PostgreSQL only in some machines

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, npgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL for the first time and I've developed a .NET 4.0 application that I install in some machines and it can connect to the server but not in other machines. I'm usint the .NET data provider Npgsql 2.2.7.0.  In my local network, I have an Windows 7 as the server and another machine with dual OS installation: Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Professional. In the Professional, the application connect to the server but not in the Ultimate.

Could somebody give me a cue about what can be the cause for those different behaviours?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Danilo da Silva

Comment: What kind of connection error do you see? Does the `pg_hba.conf` file contain entries for the servers that cannot connect? How are credentials being passed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the correct error cause. It was a problem with the System.Core dll version. After downloaded and installed an update from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556 the problem was solved.

Thanks,

Danilo da Silva